# TypeError : onSubmit is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error "TypeError : onSubmit is not a function". I am trying to make payments available for my react native app.

Here is my code :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cardData: { valid: false } };
  }
```

Here is Button. And there is that Error.

```
 render() {
    const { onSubmit, submitted, error } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <CreditCardInput requiresName onChange={(cardData) => this.setState({ cardData })} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
          <Button
            title='Subscribe'
            disabled={!this.state.cardData.valid || submitted}
            onPress={() => onSubmit(this.state.cardData)}
          />
```

Here is render :

```
 render() {
    const { submitted, error } = this.state;
    return (
        <AddSubscriptionView
          error={error}
          submitted={submitted}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you rendering this? It seems that you are either not passing the `onSubmit` prop, or passing something other than a function.

Comment: This is not complete render, but I am not sure did I understand your question.

Comment: Here is the code that I used : https://medium.com/@lyzhovnik/using-stripe-payment-service-with-react-native-and-fetch-4177c8d992cb

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof onSubmit);` output right after you get `onSubmit` from the props?

Comment: Please post all relevant code in your question (you can edit it), not external links - particularly where your actual code probably differs from what's in the link. We need to see what props are being passed to this component in the `render` method of its parent.

Comment: How are you calling the react component that contains the code? You might like to use console to print this.props

Comment: Ok, I did edit. But I think I did not do what you want.

Comment: We need the `render()` method of the parent component that is rendering the component mentioned in the second code block, the one you titled with "Here is Button, ...".

Comment: not enough code is provided. onSubmit and the way you passed it down must be here as well

Comment: I made another edit...Is it okay now?

Comment: Well you are passing `this.onSubmit` as a prop indeed, but is it defined in that same component? Can you show us that as well?

Comment: No this is another component.

Comment: Well that's the problem then, in order for you to be able to call `this.onSubmit` from a given component, the function `onSubmit` needs to be defined in that component. Otherwise, its value will be `undefined`.

Comment: I tried that after you asked me is this that same component. But I didn’t have time to check it. I will send you here as edit if I can’t make it.

Comment: I need help here. I dont know where I need to add second render.